# CSS 3D transforms works at random in Chrome 16

Tags: css, 3d

I have a really strange problem where CSS 3D transforms work sometimes and sometimes not. Before upgrading to the latest version of Chrome it always worked but with version 16 it only works at random.

More specifically it seems the -webkit-perspective doesn't take which makes everything flat (although the elements still get transformed). Changing the perspective in Chrome's "firebug" after the page has loaded doesn't affect anything either.

The page in question is here: http://exscale.se/__files/uploads/jquery-3d-circle.htm. I know there's quite a lot of code but the stuff related to the 3D transforms are all in this CSS file: http://code.google.com/p/sleekphp/source/browse/trunk/Sites/SleekBase/Modules/Base/CSS/jQuery.threeDCircle.scss

My question is: do you experience the same problem with my page or have you ever experienced this yourself? And if so, can you think of anything that triggers it?

I should mention I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and Chrome 16.0.912.63.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue in Chrome 16.09 or Safari  on the Mac. Perhaps it's a linux Chrome issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in Windows under VirtualBox. It's so strange that it's random though.

Comment: same chrome but on win7 x64: no problems. - on another matter: keep in mind that these kinda animations only look good on fast machines. I had to switch to best performance on my Lenovo X200 to see a fluent animation...

Comment: Hi. I'm currently experiencing the same problem on a linux chrome 16.0.912.63 beta. Did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out what's causing it. The strangest thing is that it works _sometimes_ without _anything_ changing in the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chromium blacklisted your GPU and refuse to do any 3d CSS.

the solution is pretty easy: turn on "override software rendering list" option in "chrome://flags".

see https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/issues/40

Comment: Sweet! That did it. So strange when it works only at random (or perhaps it wasn't as random as I first thought).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Chromium web SCM interface](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/resources/gpu_blacklist.json?revision=75130&view=markup&pathrev=75130) and check that your GPU isn't blacklisted.

Also, go to chrome://gpu/ and check that Chrome reports 3D CSS as enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I found that may be the issue.  When you use the code

```
-webkit-perspective: 600px;
```

You need to have that in the *parent* of the element you want it to affect. If it's in the actual element, it need to be combined with the transform, like so

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(45deg);
```

Comment: I assume you didn't read the entire thread because if you did you'd notice that markus found the solution about 6 months ago.

Comment: Well it helped me fix a FF issue with a 3d cardflip not working. Use --moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(45deg);