# CSS 3D transforms not working on Chrome 26 (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: css, google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium, css-transforms

On **Google Chrome ( 26.0.1410.63 )**, when I tried to open this http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/ 
It says

```
Uh-oh, your browser has no support for 3D CSS transforms.
```

I was surprised & then opened the google chrome console in that website, and did `Modernizr.csstransforms3d` it returned `false` !

Did anyone face this problem before ? It works fine when I switch to chrome on windows though, No luck with **Chromium( 25.0.1364.160 )** either. Do I need to enable any settings in chrome ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine in my Chrome browser. Try using the solution in this question:

[CSS 3D transforms works at random in Chrome 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627707/css-3d-transforms-works-at-random-in-chrome-16)

Comment: Thanks man that link to the answer you posted, solved the problem :), during my search result I've seen this question but did not open it because in my case it was not random, my bad !