# Chrome css3 animation display bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I'm trying to make an animation using css3.
basically the idea is to split up an image into cubes and rotate each cube separately by 180deg to show the image on the other side.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUvnm/2/)

I got 16 cubes like this:

```
<div class="cubeOuter" style="width: 100px; height: 75px; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px;">
  <div class="cube rotate">
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <img src="someimage.jpg" width="400" height="300" 
      style="position: absolute; display: block; left: -100px; top: 0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="front">
      <img src="anotherimage.jpg" width="400" height="300" 
      style="position: absolute; display: block; left: -100px; top: 0px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The positions are different for each block, so that they form the whole image.

It looks fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and Opera (using the latest stable versions) the sides of the cubes are showing through.
Here's an image of what chrome is rendering (the sides are red, as you can see, they're showing through the image):

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it for Chrome and Opera?

The error does't occur if there are only 2 cubes per axis (2x2, 1x2, 2x1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
Setting the perspective for .cubeOuter instead of .animating solves it, don't know why, but it works.

```
#rslider-animate .animating .cubeOuter {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
     perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUvnm/4/

Answer (score 0):

Removing following seems to work fine:

```
#rslider-animate .animating {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px; 
}
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/JUvnm/3/.

Comment: Nice, but that's not a real fix, because the cubes aren't in perspective now, doesn't look right, specially if it were a larger image.

Also, the back image now flickers while animating

Comment: Even by setting perspective to 20000px there is a tiny line there.

Comment: Well, if i set it to a high number, the line does disappear, but if i increase the amount of tiles, the line thickens and becomes visible again. Also, i do want the animation to look natural, things further away to appear smaller, so perspective is a must and it can't be such a big number

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627707/css-3d-transforms-works-at-random-in-chrome-16

Comment: That is an unrelated question, as far as i can tell

Comment: Anyway it was sth about WebKit issues with rendering etc